# Rename all .htaccess Files

Tags: terminal, rename, batch-rename

I am moving many directories to Nextcloud which does not allow to upload .htaccess Files. Therefore I need to rename them to "DOT.htaccess".

Is there an elegant and easy way to do that with the terminal (MacOSX)?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Yes, there is, using `find`: what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one `find` solution as suggested in the comment:

```
find /path/to/directory -name ".htaccess" -type f -exec bash -c '
for file; do mv "$file" "${file/.htaccess/DOT.htaccess}"; done
' bash {} +
```

The first and the last line belong to the `find` command which searches for regular files (`-type f`) with name ".htaccess" in the given directory
and executes a `bash` process with `find`'s result (`{} +`) as arguments.

The part in the single quotes are the commands executed by the bash process. 
First we loop through the arguments in a `for`-loop and assign each positional parameter to variable `file` which is then moved to its new name. 
The target filename is created using bash parameter expansion: `${file/.htaccess/DOT.htaccess}` substitutes string `.htaccess` with `DOT.htaccess` in variable `file`.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much :-)